# emacs crashed after executing list-packages and cannot recover

Tags: emacs

My emacs crashed after I innocently entered the `list-packages` command and it will not recover.

I have tried re-installing it from homebrew, all I have in the `*messages*` buffer is this message:

```
Loading /usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp/proof-general/generic/proof-site.el (source)...done
package-read-archive-contents: Wrong type argument: arrayp, (spass . [(1 1 2) nil "Emacs wrapper for DisPass" single])
```

What can I do?

Comment: Try to remove `proof-general` from your `.emacs.d/elpa` directory and from the `custom.el` file. Also, send a bug report to the maintainers of `proof-general`.

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by remove proof-general from custom.el?

Comment: Sometimes, emacs saves information about customization in a file called `custom.el`. If you have one I think it should be in `.emacs.d`.

Comment: Any Emacs crash represents a bug, possibly a serious one. Please report the problem using `M-x report-emacs-bug`. If possible, say what you were doing just before the crash. Ideal would be a recipe starting from `emacs -Q` (no init file).

Comment: I would use M-x report-emacs-bug if emacs would start :)

Comment: luckily I have my .emacs.d folder in back up.  Replacing it from back up made all good.  Something in .emacs.d killed emacs

Comment: Does Emacs not start if you use `emacs -Q` (no init file)? Use that, if that works. If Emacs created a file `emacs_backtrace.txt` in the current directory when it crashed, then include its contents in your bug report.